# jquery autocomplete composed query

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

i have a php/mysql site working, it basically tracks down tasks that should run in determinated times.
I was asked to profile the users, so one doesn't see the other's project.
So far so good, almost done, generally speaking, solved it by creating a role table and the user restrictions are in queries conditions.

I'm having a problem i didn't think it would happen. In my search/filter form i have a jquery autocomplete textarea working with DB connection, so users can search by the task name. 
Now when i (only) change the query that gets the tasks names, autocomplete doesn't work anymore!

The query is good and it returns the same results and the previous, only few results, because of the new conditions, no other changes!

working autocomplete:

html:

```
if (isset($Ptask)):
  <input title="Task" size="45" type="text" value="'.$Ptask.'" id="task" name="task" >
endif;
```

javascript:

```
$( "#task" ).autocomplete({
  source: "includes/search.php",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
  log( ui.item ? "" + ui.item.value :
  "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );}
});
```

php:

```
<?php
include ('../connect-db.php');

$q = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$qstring = "SELECT name as value FROM TASKS WHERE name LIKE '%".$q."%' AND public='1' AND active='1'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $row['value'] = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $row['value']);
  $row_set[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
?>
```

Not working with this php:

```
<?php
include ('../connect-db.php');
include ('session_check.php');
$q = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$qstring = "SELECT t.name as value 
FROM CO_SERV AS s, CO_APP AS ap, CO_USERS AS u, CO_GROUPS AS g, CO_GROUP_ROLES AS gr, TASKS AS t
WHERE name LIKE '%".$q."%' 
AND g.ID_G = u.ID_G
AND s.ID = gr.ID_S
AND g.ID_G = gr.ID_G
AND ap.ID_AP = gr.ID_AP
AND u.ID_U = '3' //example id user to test it will be a post
AND t.servico = s.ID
AND ap.ID_AP = t.app
AND t.public = '1'
AND t.ative = '1'
AND gr.ative = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $row['value'] = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $row['value']);
  $row_set[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
?>
```

This query is good and returns the same as the other, the only difference is that it is restricted to the user rights
Can't see what's the problem.

Any kind of help is appreciated :)

Best regards
Gonçalo

Comment: Check the browser console, network tab and make sure that (i) auto complete is making requests to search.php (ii) search.php produces results (iii) the results are valid JSON

Comment: In Firebug console the Response and HTML appears 'null'

Comment: Just Forget it!! the problem was the include ('../connect-db.php');

well... that connects to the production DB, i'm building things in dev so tables still doesn't exist in production!! duh! So there is no problem, all works just fine. Thanks Salman, sometimes taking some time to debug really pays off